# How to make input type value as session variable without submit button in php

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, session-variables

I want to get the latitude and longitude of a particular place when selected from the drop down. I found the following code online and its working fine. But I want to make this latitude and longitude as SESSION VARIABLE in order to use it in further pages. The code as follows,

**index.php**

```
<!doctyp html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Get Latitude and Longitude</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBygc-IYrYq3hz2Sy_1LoKFBxwDn7U_8iw&sensor=false&libraries=places&region=uk&language=en&sensor=true">
</script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

Address:
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" style="text-align: left;width:357px;direction: ltr;">
<br><br>
            latitude:<input name="latitude" class="MapLat" value="" type="text" placeholder="Latitude" style="width: 161px;" disabled>
            longitude:<input name="longitude" class="MapLon" value="" type="text" placeholder="Longitude" style="width: 161px;" disabled>

    <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 350px;width: 500px;margin: 0.6em;"></div>




<script>
     $(function () {
         var lat = 44.88623409320778,
             lng = -87.86480712897173,
             latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
             image = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png';

         //zoomControl: true,
         //zoomControlOptions: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,

         var mapOptions = {
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
             zoom: 13,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
             panControl: true,
             panControlOptions: {
                 position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
             },
             zoomControl: true,
             zoomControlOptions: {
                 style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                 position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_left
             }
         },
         map = new google.maps.Map(('map_canvas'), mapOptions),
             marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: latlng,
                 map: map,
                 icon: image
             });

         var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
         var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
             types: ["geocode"]
         });

         autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

         google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function (event) {
             infowindow.close();
             var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
             if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                 map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
             } else {
                 map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                 map.setZoom(17);
             }

             moveMarker(place.name, place.geometry.location);
             $('.MapLat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
             $('.MapLon').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
         });
         google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
             $('.MapLat').val(event.latLng.lat());
             $('.MapLon').val(event.latLng.lng());
             infowindow.close();
                     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                     geocoder.geocode({
                         "latLng":event.latLng
                     }, function (results, status) {
                         console.log(results, status);
                         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                             console.log(results);
                             var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                                 lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                                 placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
                                 latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                             moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
                             $("#searchTextField").val(results[0].formatted_address);
                         }
                     });
         });

         function moveMarker(placeName, latlng) {
             marker.setIcon(image);
             marker.setPosition(latlng);
             infowindow.setContent(placeName);
             //infowindow.open(map, marker);
         }
     });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't want to use SUBMIT BUTTON or OK BUTTON in this process. Without any button click i want to make the latitude and longitude values as SESSION VARIABLE.

Please help me out. Thanks in regards.

Comment: you can use onchange event of drop down, call ajax and set the value in session.

Comment: You can't make things $_SESSION variables without sending them to the server, so if you don't want to submit the form, you'd have to send the lat/long after they're changed/entered in the UI via AJAX

Comment: Either post lat/lng with an HTML form or make an ajax call that send lat/lng data to server and then do the work with php on your server

Answer (score 0):

```
var lat = '44.88623409320778';
var lng = '-87.86480712897173';

  $.ajax({
    url: "script.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { lat: lat, lng: lng }
  }).done( function( msg ) {
    // Complete
    })
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus + " - Please try again.")
  })
```

PHP script

```
$_SESSION[ 'lat' ] = $_POST[ 'lat' ];
```

Using ajax send the lat and lng across to the php script, get the script to store it as a session variable.

You will need jquery to complete this.

Answer (score -1):

After getting latitude and longitude values just store them in session variables, by starting a session. Already you are storing values in javascript variable from that store the values in a session.

Comment: This really isn't much help, how does he store them?  Can you suggest the process required?  Stating the obvious isn't really helpful.

Comment: Don't just jump to answer, your answer is very poor more like a comment,